# Comparing timestamps in PHP

Tags: php, time

How would I be able to return a boolean expression of true once exactly 24 hours have passed and no more?

I am using `strtotime()` to out put these two times:

```
$time1 = 1316268919;
$time2 = 1316268898;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare+times+php

Comment: the answer depends on whether you want to know 24 hours absolute time or 24 hours in that timezone, e.g. `strtotime('2011-10-30 02:00:00') - strtotime('2011-10-29 02:00:00');` in Europe/Berlin will be 90000 seconds due to DST switch on that day. Note that `strtotime` is DST aware though, so `echo strtotime('2011-10-30 02:00:00') - strtotime('2011-10-29 02:00:00 +24 hours');` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
if (($time1-$time2) == 86400) {
    // Exactly 24 hours have passed.
}
```

Comment: valid comment. but issue would arise only twice a year ;) (hmm, comment regarding DST disappeared, but was partly correct)

Comment: This is the correct answer in all cases.  DST does not need to be taken into account for the calculation.  Note the question was "24 hours", not "this same time yesterday".  So therefore if on a DST boundary, it will say that 12am (midnight) is 24 hours from 1am.  That is the correct answer as 24 hours have passed between the two times.

Comment: It depends on the precise definition of "24 hours" being used. If they mean 24 hours of precisely 60 minutes each, then your code is correct. If they mean 24 clock hours, then your code is incorrect both for DST and leap seconds. (It is very important to specify *precisely* what you want in code like this. For example, people often say "every 24 hours" to mean "same time each day", but they are not the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

24h=86400sec so, when difference of two is 86400, it's exactly 24h

n.b. twice a year could cause issue do to DST, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns the number of seconds since the Unix epoch.  So to find the difference in times, simply subtract one from another.  Then compare that difference against the number of seconds in 24 hours (24 * 60 * 60).

Answer (score 0):

```
abs($time1 - $time2) === 60 * 60 * 24
```

the abs is just in case; time2 might be bigger than time1.

If the difference in times equals 60 (seconds in a minute) * 60 * (minutes per hour) * 24 (hours for a day) = 86400, there's a day difference